# How to prove Synchronous Response to Sinusoidal forced Oscillation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In "Differential Equations" 9th edition by Nagle page 155, it essentially states that:

> If a mass-spring system (where spring and friction force are linear) is driven by an external force that is itself
> sinusoidal, the system will eventually respond "in sync" with the
> driver oscillating at the same frequency.

The textbook simply states:

> ...our experiences indicate that although the initial response of the
> system may be somewhat erratic, eventually it will respond in “sync”
> with the driver and oscillate at the same frequency.

Intuitively, this makes sense but I'm wondering how I would go about proving this.

Comment: Isn't there an example directly after this section showing how this comes about?  And there's a section called 4.10 A Closer Look at Forced Mechanical Vibrations (at least in the version I'm looking at).  That's probably where you want to look.

Comment: @march Thank you.  In quickly looking over 4.10, is seems they may address it and maybe use tools from section 4.9 and earlier to do it.  Perhaps I don't have the tools yet (as I'm only up to section 4.3) to understand the reason for synchronous response.  I was hoping that I could answer this question without the tools introduced beyond section 4.1.  Perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: This is only true if spring and friction force are linear. The forced and dampened Duffing oscillator (as model of a non-linear spring) can also show chaotic long-term behavior.

Comment: @LutzLehmann.  Thank you.  I updated the question.

Comment: It involves solving the equation $$a\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+cx=f$$ where $a,b,c$ are constants and $f$ is a continuous function. I'll expand on this more if you'd like.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thank you.  Yes, I got that part already and I can solve these, but I don't know how to use it to prove by question above.  : /

Comment: Do you know about the method of undetermined coefficients? Or first the split into homogeneous/complementary and inhomogeneous/particular solution?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I recall learning them at somebody  point in school years ago, but will be working through them again in this chapter. I suppose I’ll finish the chapter and then come back to this question if I still can’t figure it out.  Thank you!